# Powershell Select-String without *

Tags: regex, windows, git, powershell, select-string

I have a small problem I hope you can help me. I want to use "git branch" to get the current branch from the tag I defined so far so good:

I get the following output with the command : `git branch --contains TAG`

```
* develop
```

But now I only want the value : `develop` Without the star and without spaces, so just develop.

I have read that it seems to be possible with `git branch --contains TAG | select-string`, but I can't get it to work I hope one of you can help me.

Linux would be nice but i must work on powershell :(

Comment: `(git branch --contains TAG) -replace '\* '` (should work with multiple branch output) or `(git branch --contains TAG).substring(2)`. The output is just a string that you need to manipulate.

Comment: I would instead ask Git to produce the desired format directly instead of parsing the output, e.g. `--format=%(refname)` or `--format=%(refname:lstrip=-1)` (see the [docs](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt) for more details).

Comment: Or use `(git branch --contains TAG) -replace '[* ]'`, or `((git branch --contains TAG) -split ' ', 2)[1]` or `(git branch --contains TAG).Substring(2)` or .....

Comment: Thank you very very much Guys I use (git branch --contains TAG).substring(2) and it would work perfectly :)